# SSH connection issue with Git

Tags: git, ssh

Got remote repositories on Bitbucket and Github, the issue is the same on both.

I do a `git pull` but it times out and returns:
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I just moved to our new office, and I have the feeling this might have something to do with the net perhaps, as it worked perfectly from home last night.

Any ideas on what the next step should be? I can access our own router, but the general internet is shared across the building we are located in.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Not that I know of, just plugged our router to the connection in the wall to give us WIFI (testing with cable though)

Comment: @ioseph I will try and check with the landlord if theres any proxy or anything on the general net.

Answer (score 1):

If ssh is somehow blocked, you can test with an https url:

```
cd /your/repo
git remote set-url origin https://YourLogin@github.com/YourLogin/YourRepo
git fetch
```

You will have to enter your GitHub account password.